# Image Binding in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

What I want to do here is that if an item is selected in Longlist than it should display corresponding image  based on imageurl assigned to that item.But the image is not getting displayed in DetailsPage.xaml
I have no idea where am I making the mistake.Please guide me

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace PivotApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + (MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).ID, UriKind.Relative));


        MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;

    }


}
```

}

**DetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace PivotApp1
{    
public partial class DetailsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public DetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        DataContext = App.ViewModel;

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }


}
```

}

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
namespace PivotApp1.ViewModels
{
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";

    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _sampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _sampleProperty)
            {
                _sampleProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    public string LocalizedSampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return AppResources.SampleProperty;
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }







    public void LoadData()
    {

        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "Shri Ganesh Aarti", LineThree = "/images/icons/durgamaa.jpg" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID= "1", LineOne = "Shri Hanuman Aarti", LineThree = "/images/icons/GaneshJi.jpg" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID= "2", LineOne = "Maa Durga Aarti",  LineThree = "/images/icons/icons/Sheravaalimaa.jpg" });



        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}






    }
```

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```
namespace PivotApp1.ViewModels
{
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _id;

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }


    private string _lineOne;

    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }


    private string _lineThree;

    public string LineThree
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineThree;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineThree)
            {
                _lineThree = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineThree");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**DetailsPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PivotApp1.DetailsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" d:DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,10,0,0" Height="429" Width="470" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <Image Source="{Binding Path=LineThree}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="390" Height="400"></Image>
      <!--  <Image Source="/images/icons/GaneshJi.jpg"></Image>-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Allright, now What's wrong?

Comment: What's the `DataContext` of your DetailsPage.xaml?

Comment: after binding image is not getting displayed on Detailspage.xaml

Comment: What is the `Build Action` of the image files?

Comment: @Tobias   DataContext = App.ViewModel;

Comment: @LeftyCoder Build Action is set to "Content"

Comment: Can you post your project structure and make sure that the `Copy to Output Directory` property for your images is set to "Copy Always"?

Comment: @LeftyCoder changed to "Copy Always" still not working.Added more project files

Comment: Do you see the images if you remove the binding and set the source directly?  I see where you have an image commented out in the xaml that has the source hard coded.

Comment: @LeftyCoder  after I removed binding and source directly image is getting displayed

Comment: I don't see where you are setting your selected item as the datacontext of the detailspage after selecting an item in the long listselctor.

Comment: @LeftyCoder  Actually I am trying data binding for the first time so I am not sure what should be done.What I want to do here is that if an item is selected in Longlist than it should display corresponding image url assigned to that item.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are setting the `DataContext` to your selected item on the Details Page when you navigate to it.  Try changing the `OnNavigatedTo` method to the code below in **DetailsPage.xaml.cs**.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     string selectedItem = null;

     if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("SelectedItem"))
     {
          selectedItem = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedItem"];
     }

     if (selectedItem != null)
     {
          DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items.Where(p => string.Compare(selectedItem, p.ID) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
     }
}
```

You'll also want to remove the line `DataContext = App.ViewModel;` from the **DetailsPage.xaml.cs** constructor.

Comment: still not working after modifying as you said.I think string type is need to be converted to Uri type during binding . What do you say?